# GStreamer video streaming low performance

Tags: gstreamer

I am streaming GStreamer's videotestsrc from a raspberry pi. The stream must be TCP.

My Server Pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc horizontal-speed=5 ! x264enc tune="zerolatency" threads=1 ! mpegtsmux ! tcpserversink host=10.0.0.7 port=3344
```

My client pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc port=3344 host=10.0.0.7 ! tsdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

It does work, I get the wanted video on the client in an OpenGL window. But:

1. The raspberry pi needs a lot of CPU power, about 60%.
2. The quality is very bad. I keep getting some corrupted areas all the time, for example rectangles with the wrong color and the video keeps getting stuck sometimes for a short time.
3. I get errors like this in the client terminal: error while decoding MB 5 13, bytestream 2817

I have used https://github.com/silvanmelchior/RPi_Cam_Web_Interface before (using the raspberry pi camera instead of videotestsrc of course). It has very low latency, good quality and almost no CPU power. But it is written in PHP and I would like to implement the stream in a c++ application. GStreamer seems to be a good choice for me, as these jobs are what it was created for. I also use GStreamer for Audio Streaming fine.

My questions are:

1. Why does GStreamer require that lot of CPU power, whilst `RPi_Cam_Web_Interface` requires almost none? Is it a problem with `videotestsrc` (because it is created realtime) ?
2. Why is my quality so bad, even when using the loopback interface and the same computer as server and client?
3. What can I do to improve the efficiency and quality of my setup?

Comment: `videotestsrc` does indeed create samples as fast as possible. You can mimic a live source by passing `is-live=true` for the `videotestsrc`. Also RPi has support for H.264 hardware encoding (I think). `x264enc` works in software, that makes a big difference. Check how to use the hardware encoder of the RPi via GStreamer.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, videotestsrc was the problem. I recorded the videotestsrc to a file and then played the file to a tcpserversink. All problems gone.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your cpu load by using decodebin instead of avdec_h264.
I am also trying to increase performance if any knows please help

Comment: Hi, I resolved my problems and I am quite good at gstreamer now. If you try to do what I did I recommend you to record your videostestsrc to a filesink and then play the file. Apparently it also works with adding live=true to the videotestsrc, I didn't try it. The problem is that videotestsrc creates as much images as it can, which causes a lot of cpu usage.

Answer (score 0):

- You are using the same raspberry pi for server and client pipelines, so they use same soc resouces, the it uses more cpu power and emit heat, it is better to attach heatsink to the raspberry pi.
- If you have another PC or raspberry pi you can use it to debug for findout the bad quality occurs in server side or client side or server client mix operation in the previos scenario.
- You can try different framerates using caps inside your pipelines, then change the frame rates and see the diferences of the output video quality. and try v4l2src for the server pipeline and change the resolutions and check the diferences of the output scenarios. These are the steps i followed to optimize my streaming pipelines